# Connecting through VNC to an Shared Image from another Google Cloud Project

Tags: ssh, gcloud, vnc, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

I am recently working on a project in Google Cloud Compute Engine, and I have created an image of my current work. In this instance I can access using VNC Viewer to a GUI like of the instance by using the public IP and the port :5901 .

I gave the permissions to another person to use this image in his own proyect, but although he can start the instance created from my image, he cant access using VNC and the public IP (timeout problem).

I guess it has to do with anything related to the SSH protocol, but I dont know exactly how.

Does anyone has an idea of how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found the asnwer in a youtube video: [Here](https://youtu.be/oYso_F7GW3A?t=652), (10:52) I just had to habilitate the tcp ports on my project. Thanks!

I had to go to **firewall configuration**, add **firewall a rule** that habilitates all tcp ports from 0.0.0.0/0 for incoming connections in all instances since I'll be using more than one instance in my project.

Honestly I don't know if I did "overdo" anything, but it worked for me.

Comment: Could you describe (by editing this answer) in a few line the idea behind the solution proposed in the video?

Comment: Oh, ok it is Done :)